# Using different registers in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

I have been using some registers interchangeably (especially for $t0 and $s0), and it seems no big problem, probably because I'm currently working on some very simple programs.

Are there any rules for using different registers in MIPS?

When should we use $t0-$t9 or $s0-$s7 or $a0-$a3 or $v0-$v1 ?

Comment: Consult calling convention documentation, or [wikipedia for an overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms881468.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIPS is intentionally designed so that no registers are "special".  As long as your agree with any other software functions your code has to interact with (calling convention / ABI), you can do whatever is most efficient.

And there are *many* choices that are equally efficient, because the general-purpose registers are truly general-purpose;  The stack pointer is just a software convention; there's no `push` instruction that uses it implicitly.  It's not faster or better or anything else to use `$t0` instead of `$t3` as a temporary.

---

There is at least one exception to this rule: `jal` writes the return address to `$31` (the link register) implicitly.  (http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html).  Using 5 bits to encode a destination register would have taken those 5 bits away from the immediate branch-target.

Of course, calling conventions for platforms are designed around any implicit register usages in the instruction-set, so of course called functions expect their return address in `$31`, which by convention is called `$ra` (return address) on MIPS.